# Path for tags in VIM for multiple projects

Tags: ctags, vim, exuberant-ctags

I've recently started using ctags on my projects. I currently have the following setup:

```
root/tags [contains all non-static tags]
root/foo/tags [contains static tags for the foo directory]
root/bar/tags [static]
root/something/else/tags [etc.]
...
```

I can `set tags=./tags,tags,/path/to/root/tags` and everything works perfectly.

However, my problem is that I work on several projects at once, so I have, for example, `/path/to/root1`, `/path/to/root2`, and `/path/to/root3` all at once. I'd rather not manually set the tags each time I open a file; is there any way I can have tags to to the `/path/to/rootX` based on the file I'm editting? (i.e., if I'm editing `/path/to/root3/foo/x.c`, use the tags in `root3/tags`?

In my case, all of my projects share a common parent directory; what I really want is something like:

```
set tags=./tags,tags,substitute("%:p:h", "\(^\/path\/to\/.*/\).*$", "\1", "")
```

but I can't seem to get the right vimfu to make it work.

EDIT: I just realized that this won't work; I can't actually write to `root*`. Instead, I'd like to store my main ctags file in `~/ctags/root*/tags`, where there's a 1:1 mapping between the subdirectories of `~/ctags/` and `/path/to/` [For those who may be wondering, these are ClearCase UCM dynamic views; neither `/view/XXX/` nor `/view/XXX/vobs/` is writable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is:

```
set tags=./tags,tags,substitute("%:p:h", "\(^\/path\/to\/.*/\).*$", "\1", "")
```

Try:

```
let &tags = './tags,tags,' . substitute(expand("%:p:h"), "\(^\/path\/to\/.*/\).*$", "\1", "")
```

There's no expansion in a `:set` command.  Also, "%:p:h" won't be expanded automatically, so use `expand()`.  See:

```
:help :let-option
:help expand()
```